# Calling ROS2 subscriber callback function from another function

Tags: ros2, ubuntu, c++, publisher, subscribe

I try to use x and y in timer_callback function but I get ‘x’ was not declared in this scope I don't know how can I do this

```
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
#include "geometry_msgs/msg/pose_stamped.hpp"

using std::placeholders::_1;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

class MainA : public rclcpp::Node
{
  public:
  MainA(): Node("main"), count_(0)
  {
     gosub_ = this->create_subscription<geometry_msgs::msg::PoseStamped>(
      "sol",10,std::bind(&MainA::sub_callback, this,_1));
  publisher_ = this->create_publisher<geometry_msgs::msg::PoseStamped>(
    "/checkpoint", 10);
  timer_ = this->create_wall_timer(
  500ms, std::bind(&MainA::timer_callback, this));
 } 

 private: 
void sub_callback(const geometry_msgs::msg::PoseStamped & msg) const
{
  x = msg.pose.position.x;
  y = msg.pose.position.y;
}
void timer_callback(){
  auto message = geometry_msgs::msg::PoseStamped();
  message.header.frame_id = "map";
  message.header.stamp = this->now();
  message.pose.position.x = x;
  message.pose.position.y = y;
  message.pose.position.z = 0.0;
  
  publisher_->publish(message);
}
rclcpp::TimerBase::SharedPtr timer_;
rclcpp::Subscription<geometry_msgs::msg::PoseStamped>::SharedPtr gosub_;
rclcpp::Publisher<geometry_msgs::msg::PoseStamped>::SharedPtr publisher_;
size_t count_;
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
rclcpp::spin(std::make_shared<MainA>());
rclcpp::shutdown();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please edit you post to include an explicit question as well as how to reproduce your problem, what you've tried to do to debug or solve it. It seems like you're having trouble with scoping of variables but this isn't specific enough that someone can answer your question conclusively as it's too open ended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a quick look, it seems that you missed the declaration of the variable `x` and `y` in your code. In C++ you need to declare every variable you want to use.

You may solve by adding the declaration right after `size_t count`:

```
size_t count;
double x;
double y;
```